# Retail Price for MAP enabled product in product view reloads to Special Price

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I wanted to show the retail price for MAP enabled products. I tried to edit the view.phtml file and did this:

```
                <div class="pro-info">
                <?php if($_product->getData('msrp_enabled') == 1): ?>
                <div class="price-box">
                        <p class="regular-price">
                            <span class="price-label">Retail Price:</span>
                            <span id="product-price-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" class="price">
                                <span class="price">
                                    <?php echo $this->helper('core')->formatPrice($_product->getPrice(), false) ?>
                                </span>                                    
                            </span>
                        </p>
                </div>
                <?php  endif;?>
```

And this displayed the Retail Price but the problem is; For some products it will display the special price. First when the site is loading it will display retail price and then suddenly change and show the special price instead.
I tried to view source of the page via Ctrl+U and it displays original price in Retail Price but in the frontend page it displays special price.

I also noticed that for some product `Product.OptionsPrice([])` has values in it and for some it doesn't. And whichever product has values in `Product.OptionsPrice([])` has the issue.
Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had something to do with the id in the span tag.

```
<span id="product-price-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" class="price">
```

Changed it to `<span id="old-price-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" class="price">`